# Access attribute chain in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to create the following relationships in Python:

- A can be followed by B or C
- B can be followed by A
- C can be followed by A

My current approach is based on this class

```py
class Element:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.followers = {}

    def add_follower(self, follower):
        self.followers[follower.name] = follower
        setattr(self, follower.name.lower(), follower)

    def help(self):
        return f"Help for {self.name}"

element_a = Element('A')
element_b = Element('B')
element_c = Element('C')

element_a.add_follower(element_b)
element_a.add_follower(element_c)
element_b.add_follower(element_a)
element_c.add_follower(element_a)
```

This works nicely. When I type `element_a.b.a.c.help()` in the REPL, I get `'Help for C'`. Furthermore, while typing in the REPL, e.g. `element_a.b.a.` I get `b` and `c` as completion candidates which is exactly what I want (always seeing what the next allowed elements are).

However, now I would like to have a history method which returns the taken sequence, e.g. `element_a.b.a.c.history()` should return `["A", "B", "A", "C"]`. And this is where I am stuck.

My first idea was to have `add_follower()` to set a `parent` attribute which I could use to reconstruct the chain but this did not work.
Calling `....history()` would only return the last element, e.g. `...a.c.history()` returns `["A"]`.

As far as I understand, this makes sense, because `add_follower()` creates a reference to the object and creates it only once. Thus, the parent will only be set one time.

Thus, is there a way to

- set the relationship between the elements and have them available while typing (completion candidates)
- recunstruct the sequence upon demand?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems quite complicated and convoluted.

What you are doing directly is not possible: you have only one "A" in all this. So, there can't be a different response in `element_a.history()` and `element_a.b.a.b.a.c.a.history()`. Those are the same object.

Or more simply, `element_a.b` is the same object as `b`, so `element_a.b.history()` cannot be different than `b.history()`

So, if you need it to be different, `element_a.b` must not return `element_b`.
It must return a new `b`. A new element whose name is b.
And that has a pointer to its ancestor `element_a`, so that it is able to tells its history.

So `element_a` must have an attribute `b` and an attribute `c` whose ancestor is `element_a`.
And `element_a.b` must have an attribute `a` whose ancestor is `element_a.b`. So obviously not the same as `element_a`
And that `element_a.b.a` must have an attribute `b` and an attribute `c` whose ancestor are `element_a.b.a`. Etc.

All those are different instances, with different ancestors. Otherwise, no specific history.

It could be tempting to do something like

```
class Element:
    def __init__(self, name, ancestor=None):
        self.name=name
        self.daddy=ancestor
        if name=='A':
            self.b=Element('B', self)
            self.c=Element('C', self)
        elif name=='B':
            self.a=Element('A', self)
        elif name=='C':
            self.a=Element('A', self)
```

But then, of course, the construction itself enters an infinite recursion loop. Which, after all, makes sense, since this is exactly what you want: to have implicitly defined an infinite tree of attributes.

So, the only possibility I see is that the element is created only when accessing it (which is implicily what you want, when you talk about the REPL completion... I don't get exactly what you are trying to do. But it looks like some game with the interactive interpreter)

This is possible through `__getattr__` and `__getattribute__`.

So, a closer possibility would be

```py
class Element:
    def __init__(self, name, daddy=None):
        self.name=name
        self.daddy=daddy
    def __getattr__(self, x):
        if x in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
            return Element(x.upper(), self)
    def history(self):
        res=[]
        s=self
        while s is not None:
            res.append(s.name)
            s=s.daddy
        return res[::-1]
```

Then you can try `Element('A').a.b.a.c.a.c.a.b.a.history()`.

Sure, I haven't done anything yet to prevent `Element('A').a.a.a.b.b.b.history()` to work as well. I could (in `getattr` for example). But that is not the correct way yet, since here we don't have something that seems important to you: the `b` and `c` completion when trying to "TAB" from a `A` value.

Because there is no attribute `b` and `c` to `Element('A')`. They will be created only when we access them. But they don't exist before. So, they have no reason to appear in the list of attributes for the completion.

So for that, we would like to have those attributes existing

```py
class Element:
    def __init__(self, name, daddy=None):
        self.name=name
        self.daddy=daddy
        if name=='A':
             self.b=True
             self.c=True
        elif name in ['B', 'C']:
             self.a=True
    def __getattr__(self, x):
        if x in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
            return Element(x.upper(), self)
    def history(self):
        res=[]
        s=self
        while s is not None:
            res.append(s.name)
            s=s.daddy
        return res[::-1]
```

Here attributes exist for REPL.
But when I try `a=Element('A')` and then `a.b` I just get `True`. And therefore `a.b.history()` just fails.

That is because `__getattr__` is not even called when attribute already exist.

So, we need the next thing: `__getattribute__` which is trickier to handle. `__getattribute__` is called even if attribute exist. Which means that any attribute we use anywhere in the code (`.name`, `.history()`, `.daddy`, ...) goes through this method. So it better be working.
But if this method returns `self.name` when it is asked for value of `name` attribute... it calls itself, since `self.name` is `self.__getattribute__('name')`, and we fall back in an endless recursion loop.

The method is to call explicitly the `object.__getattribute__` generic `getattribute` method to access our attributes.

But to make an execption for `a`, `b` and `c` attributes.

Hence my answer:

```py
class Element:
    def __init__(self, name, daddy=None):
        self.name = name
        self.daddy = daddy
        if name=='A':
            self.b=True
            self.c=True
        elif name=='B':
            self.a=True
        elif name=='C':
            self.a=True

    def __getattribute__(self, x):
        r=object.__getattribute__(self, x)
        if x in ['a','b','c']:
            return Element(x.upper(), self)
        return r

    def history(self):
        l=[]
        t=self
        while t is not None:
            l.append(t.name)
            t=t.daddy
        return l[::-1]

    def help(self):
        return f"Help for {self.name}"

a=Element("A")
b=Element("B")
c=Element("C")
```

So here `a.b.a.b.a.c.a.b.history()` works. And `a.a.history()` wouldn't.

The existence of attributes `a`, `b`, `c` (depending on the names) ensure that the REPL completion works.

The fact that we return the actual value of the attributes in `__getattribute__` (that is called even if those attributes exists) ensure that it is not the `True` value that we return, but a new `Element`.
If we try to get an attribute that doesn't exist, `object.__getattribute__` will raise an error, as expected.

And because I put the `r=object.__getattribute__(self,x)` before dealing with the `a`,`b`,`c` exceptions, I ensure that it will raise an error also if we are trying to access `a`,`b` or `c` when it is not supposed to exist. So I don't have to reimplement here the succession rules. All I need to do is *"if this is one of the special attribute, and I am still alive — if it wasn't authorized, I would have failed before, in `object.__getattribute__` — then this is how we access those special attributes"*

If I had written

```
def __getattribute__(self, x):
        if x in ['a','b','c']:
            return Element(x.upper(), self)
        return object.__getattribute__(self, x)
```

instead, then `a.a.history()` would return `['A', 'A']`. Even tho `a.<TAB>` would not show `a` as a possible completion for `a.`, `a.a` would still work once typed anyway without the use of completion.
But because I called `object.__getattribute__` before, the call would fail even before reaching the `if x in ...` when trying to access to `a.a`

So, the attributes `a`, `b`, `c` whose value is True serve 2 purposes

- Ensure that they appear in attributes list, so that completion shows them
- Enforce the "successor" rule: if that attribute is not present, not only it would not appear in the completion list, but because we called inconditionaly (even for the special cases of `a`,`b`,`c`) `object.__getattribute__` an access to an illegal successor would fail

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed response!